# Using var vs not using var in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

On my first acquaintance with Google Apps Script I wrote a script which picks three files on my Drive and writes the full paths to them in a text file. It seems to be working fine. getFullPathById(id) is another function I wrote which is irrelevant here.

```
function main() {
  outputfilename = "out.txt"
  content = ""

  var i = 0
  allfiles = DriveApp.getFiles()
  while (i < 3 && allfiles.hasNext())
  {
    file = allfiles.next()
    content += getFullPathById(file.getId())
    i = i + 1
    console.log(i)
  }

  DriveApp.createFile(outputfilename, content)
}
```

Though when instead of `var i = 0` I simply wrote `i = 0` it processed not three files but two, and logged `2 2 4` to console instead of `1 2 3`. Further when I changed `i < 3` to `i < 5`, it processed not 5 but twenty-something files. Where I, a newbie in Google Apps Script, can read about differences between writing `var i = 0` and `i = 0`?

Comment: Do you have `i` defined at the global level outside of the `main()` function or in other scripts in your GAS project? If so, your `main()`function is likely referencing some other declaration of `i`. Variables declared using `var` are hoisted so that they are scoped to the function they are in. Use of `var` is now discouraged in favor of `let` and `const` which are block-scoped.

Comment: Did @TheAddonDepot comment answer your question? You can also read more information about this in the following [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488).

Comment: @GiselleValladares pretty much yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki for visibility, since the solution was provided by [@TheAddonDepot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6586255/theaddondepot) in the comments section.

`var i = 1` declares variable x in current scope (aka execution context). If the declaration appears in a function - a local variable is declared; if it's in global scope - a global variable is declared.

`i = 1`, on the other hand, is merely a property assignment. It first tries to resolve x against scope chain. If it finds it anywhere in that scope chain, it performs assignment; if it doesn't find x, only then does it creates the `i` property on a global object (which is a top level object in a scope chain).

Also, as mentioned by  [@TheAddonDepot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6586255/theaddondepot). The use of var is now discouraged in favor of `let` and `const`, you can read more information about the difference between `var`,  `let` and `const` in the following blogs:

- [Var, Let, and Const – What's the Difference?](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/)
- [Difference between var, let and const keywords in JavaScript](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-var-let-and-const-keywords-in-javascript/)